# Go to a long path in Windows Registry Editor

Tags: windows, windows-registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open registry directly to given key?](https://superuser.com/questions/115854/open-registry-directly-to-given-key)

Say if I need to edit a key in this path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`.

Is there a quick "Go To" way by copy/paste this path to locate the registry key? Otherwise I have to alt-tab switch between the website indicates this long path and Registry Editor a couple times to find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[RegJump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963880) has been written for this purpose. :-)

Comment: What an amazingly, truly astonishingly **stoopid** thing not to have added actually into regedit by now. *sigh* Thanks Tom (and thanks Mark!)